# Saving state of html page with webgl iframe to hard drive

Tags: html, 3d, webgl

I have a html doc with webgl 3d model in the iframe, within the doc we can change the state of the 3d model color, shape, i want to save the state of that into the hard drive so when opened we can retrieve the same 3d model on the drive. any ideas

Comment: There are some good tutorials on this you may find and answer on youtube.

Comment: Basically you can't. WebGL is not just a diagram it's an API. To re-draw what you see requires code and that code (a) needs a server, because WebGL is not allowed to use images without CORS permissions and running from a hard drive does not give those permission and (b) because the code that drew the 3d model will likely be referencing things on the net, not your hard drive. This is no different than trying to save the state of Facebook.com or gmail.com to your hard drive. Try it. It won't work.